# UITableViewCell repeating with scrollview - What workarounds are there?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

So, my problem is pretty simple. I have a UITableView in a UIViewController. The tableview has dynamic cells (custom cells with images , text, etc.. from a subclass I created) and these cells belong to a subclass I created. Everything is going fine since the content is different on each cell. The problem is that when I scroll the scrollview of the cell which is horizontal ( I have a UIScrollView in the subview of the cell. I created this scrollview on the cell subclass), on let's say, indexPath.row == 0, and scroll the tableview vertically, after about 8 cells, the ninth cell has the scrollview scrolled as well. This is because of dequeuereusablecells, so the ninth cell is actually the first one, only displaying different content but since it is the first cell, it has the same background operation (the scrollview scrolled).

I tried to unscroll in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` but although this solves the problem it creates another : The first cell that was scrolled is not anymore. So, to solve this new problem I am planning on adding a workaround here that is a dictionary of [Int:Bool], that is, the indexPath corresponding to a Boolean value. If I scrolled the first cell, then 0:true. If I reach the ninth cell (which is equal to the first cell, but with IndexPath = 8 ), I unscroll the cell's horizontal scrollview. If I come back to the beginning of the tableview and reach the first cell, I scroll the cell's horizontal scrollview back. What do you guys think?

The other workaround I can think of is just not use dequeue reusable cells since I don't think I will have more than 30-50 rows on my tableview. 
In terms of performance, which operation is better?

Comment: You can implement the -prepareForReuse method on the cell class, store the scrollview offset somewhere (not in the cell of course) then reset the scrollview's contentOffset of the cell. 
When the tableview if returning a reused cell in -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: you can set its scrollview's offset to the stored value (if there is any offset value stored for that indexpath).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would suggest you to carefully analyse whether removing scrolling offset from the first cell is such a bad idea. If I am a user and I scroll down to the very bottom, making the first cell invisible, are you sure that I want it to return to the scrolled position after I scroll back to top? The answer might be Yes, but you should think about this carefully because it might lead you to the simplest solution.

However, in case you really need to do it, I would have a variable which stores the state of the scrolling for each row. If you have an array of objects from which you pull necessary properties (title, image etc) you can add this as an extra property to these objects. Otherwise, you can create an array which will be storing this info (I would prefer an array over dictionary for this task).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion with the property thing. I will accept your answer since I hadn't considered that simpler implementation. However, about whether I should go for "remembering" the indexes I horizontally scrolled or not, I candidly ask you ( Please answer as the analogy is really similar): Wouldn't be better for users if they could see a list of dishes on a restaurant and scrolled horizontally on each cell to see a description of these dishes, and the tableview could remember the dishes scrolled so that he could compare dishes "far away" without having to scroll these same cells again?

Comment: Sorry for a late reply. Regarding your example I would say that in this kind of a situation a user would expect to be able to *select* dishes of interest and to then tap "compare this" and either get redirected to next view with an interface optimised for comparison OR get the cells which were not selected filtered out. And in the last case you are right - you would want to preserve the scrolling state. However, I think you will agree that comparing something that doesn't fit on one screen is not easy :)

Answer (score -1):

Fundamentally it's an issue caused by table view cell reusability. You can have workarounds, but I'd say that, things that aren't supposed to be reused should not be reused.

If your cells are all similar (with minor differences), you could use just one cell identifier; If you have very different types of cells, say, one type has a horizontal scroll view inside, one type just has some labels and images, you might want to consider to have two identifiers, so cells that have UIScrollView won't be reused for normal cells.

And at the same time, you can still do necessary cleanup works in `prepareForReuse:` to make sure cells that just get dequeued have a fresh start.